# Which mercenaries does the bishop apply to?

Tags: condottiere

In "Condottiere", 3rd edition, the bishop's rule sounds ambiguous.

It makes the players discard "all of the highest strength mercenary cards".

But if we have the following cards on the table :

- Player 1: [1] [6]
- Player 2: [3] [5]

Would the bishop apply on only the 6 or on both the 6 and the 5?

Is it all of the highest strength cards for a single battle line? Or for all the battle lines?

Answer (score 1):

The way the [rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/fe/89/fe89b26f-1524-4943-88af-a1165509cfbb/condottiere_rules_english.pdf) are worded:

> When a Bishop card is played, all of the highest-strength Mercenary card(s) **in play** are discarded.

(emphasis mine)

and the specific example they choose to highlight (where two players have the highest-strength card):

> *Example: In a two-player game, Chris has one 6- strength, one 3-strength, and two 1-strength Mercenary cards in his battle line. Scott has one 6-strength and two 1-strength Mercenary cards in his battle line
> and plays a Bishop card. Since the highest-strength Mercenary card in play is 6, all 6-strength Mercenary cards are discarded from both players’ battle lines (even the player that played the Bishop card).*

lead me to think that in your situation, it would only apply to the 6, not the 5. The words 'in play', when interpreted naturally, apply to the board state in its entirety. The example seems to highlight a specific situation which won't happen all the time.

Comment: To me, the example might be interpreted as both "the highest cards in play" and "the highest cards for each player's row", and to me this casts a doubt.

But I guess that the interpretation you make of the rules makes sense, in the (French) version I use, that's even more ambiguous since the rule for the Spring cards states that it adds 3 to the highest cards "in play with the highest value of all the battle lines", this precision isn't present for the bishop's card and that difference doesn't seem to be present in the English version.